# angular - retrieving json from a factory

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Trying to get the factory (below) to retrieve a json file. Do you know what is wrong? (Angular v.1.3.x-beta)

**HTML**

```
<div class="search">
  <input type="text" ng-model="query" ng-model-options="{debounce:750}" ng-change="updateSearch()"/>
</div>
{{results | json}}
```

**JS**

```
directory.controller('DirectorySearchController', function($scope, searchFactory) {
  $scope.updateSearch = function() {
    $formatted = $scope.query.replace(/\s{1,}/g, '+');
    if($scope.query != '') {
        $scope.results = searchFactory.simpleSearch($formatted);
    } else {
        $scope.results = '';
    }
  };
});

directory.factory('searchFactory', function($http) {
  var urlBase = 'http://example.com/api';
  var searchFactory = {};
  searchFactory.simpleSearch = function (keyword) {
    return $http.get(urlBase + '/search/' + keyword);
  };
  return searchFactory;
});
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code the factory returns a promise, and automatic promise unwrapping is not available in new versions of angular. Try this

```
searchFactory.simpleSearch($formatted).success(function(data){
  $scope.results=data;
});
```